# Исключение в firebase: This operation is not allowed. This may be because the given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Что не так обычная регистрация по телефону и коду в Firebase, причем все работало теперь стабильно вот что выкидывает:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This operation is not allowed. This may be because the given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.
```

Вот код где выкидывает:

```
callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                L.i( "onVerificationCompleted:$credential")
                //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                L.i("onVerificationFailed" + e)
                if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                } else if (e is FirebaseAuthMissingActivityForRecaptchaException) {
                    // reCAPTCHA verification attempted with null Activity
                }
                // Show a message and update the UI
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken,
            ) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                L.i( "onCodeSent:$verificationId")
                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                storedVerificationId = verificationId
                resendToken = token
            }
        }
```

Что оно хочет вот я все повключал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]